# I need help for determining where the unsupported operand type is located?

Tags: python

I am writing a small program in **Python 3.8**, which determines the Minimum number, Mean, Median, Lower Quartile, Upper Quartile, and Maximum number from a list of numbers, inputted from a user. However, when using the **median()** function, from the statistics module, I am running into an error: the module says that the list of numbers is an **unsupported operand type**. I have tried converting it into an integer, string, list, and array yet, none of these seem to satisfy. My code is below.

```
import statistics

#Gather input from user, and determine the minimum and maximum of said input.
k = 0
print("Welcome to Auto 5 Number Summary\nLowest Number\nLower Quartile\nMean\nUpper Quartile\nHighest Number")

a = input("\n\nEnter your numbers\n>>").split()

m = a
mn = min(m)
mx = max(m)

print("Min: ", mn)

#Mean for the list.
x = int(m[0])
b = 1
for n in range(len(m)):
    if b == len(m):
        v = int(len(m))
        print ("Mean: ", x / v)
        break
    t = int(m[b])
    x = x + t
    b += 1

m = sorted(m)
y = []
mid = len(m)

#Lower Quartile for list.
if len(m) % 2 == 0:
    kk = int(len(m))
    kk = int(kk / 2)
    lowerhalf = m[:kk]
    #lowerhalf = float(lowerhalf)
    lq = statistics.median(lowerhalf)
    print ("LQ: ", lq)

elif len(m) % 2 != 0:
    kk = int(len(m))
    kk = int(kk - 1)
    kk = int(kk / 2)
    lowerhalf = m[:kk]
    lq = statistics.median(lowerhalf)
    print("LQ: ", lq)

#Median of entire list.
print ("Median: ", statistics.median(m))

#Upper quartile for list.
if len(m) % 2 == 0:
    kk = int(len(m))
    kk = int(kk / 2)
    upperhalf = m[kk:]
    upperhalf = float(upperhalf)
    lq = statistics.median(upperhalf)
    print ("UQ: ", lq)

elif len(m) % 2 != 0:
    kk = int(len(m))
    kk = int(kk + 1)
    kk = int(kk / 2)
    upperhalf = m[kk:]
    lq = statistics.median(upperhalf)
    print("UQ: ", lq)
```

I am hoping the answer to this issue can be found. I have spent days trying new things, methods, and answers from google to resolve the error, but nothing has worked. I thank anyone who looks over this question; I would be extremely grateful for any help.

*Kind Regards,*

*Nigel.*

Comment: please post the full error message inlcuding the stack trace, this will tell you *exactly* where the error is happening.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and check the argument type.

Comment: Try commenting -->  upperhalf = float(upperhalf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of strings to the median function. It expects numeric data ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median)).

You should add a data conversion from string:

```
a = input("\n\nEnter your numbers\n>>").split()
m = list(map(int, a))
# OR
m = list(map(float, a))
```

You can then remove all other conversions, eg:

```
upperhalf = float(upperhalf)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rami. Your solution worked perfectly. However, I don't quite understand how it fixed the issue. I understand what it's doing, but that's it. I want to know what each part of it does so I can utilize it for future code. So what does the line m = list(map(float, a)) actually mean. Please, can you dissect it for me.

Comment: "m" is the value you use in your code to determine each value (median, quartile, etc), so I decided it's quicker to use m instead of changing "a".
The code is pretty straightforward, I use "map()" to apply the "int" (or "float") function to every value of the string list "a". It's at this step that the conversion takes place.
Then I use "list()" on the result, because "map()" returns a map object and you expect a list.